# Extracting text from very similar HTML tags

Tags: python-3.x

I read through the bs4 documentation but I wasnt able to find a means to extract just the names of the speakers and their corporate titles from the HTML below (e.g. name = Jonathan Tan, title = Managing Director). Can anyone help me with this?

Also, while I have learned some basics, what's the best way to improve my ability to select and extract information from HTML?

```
#generate a list of useful urls 
url_list = []


url = "http://www.fccsingapore.com/events/upcoming-events"
webpage_response = requests.get(url)
webpage = webpage_response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

all_href = soup.find_all("a")
for link in all_href:
    if "http://www.fccsingapore.com/events" in link.get("href"):
        url_list.append(link.get("href"))

counter = 0
for i in url_list:
    counter += 1
print("The program has " + str(counter) + " events to output.")

#extract useful information from each link 
for link in url_list[:1]:
    webpage_response = requests.get(link)
    event = BeautifulSoup(webpage_response.content, "html.parser")
    title = event.find("h1").get_text()
    date_and_time = event.find("div", attrs={"class":"field field-name-event-date-formated field-type-ds field-label-above"})
    date_time = date_and_time.find("div", attrs={"class":"field-item even"})
    event_date = date_time.text[:11]
    event_time = date_time.text[12:]

    address_details = event.find("div", attrs={"class":"field field-name-field-address field-type-text-long field-label-above"})
    address = address_details.find("div", attrs={"field-item even"}).get_text()

    reg_details = event.find("div", attrs={"class":"field field-name-event-reg-date-format field-type-ds field-label-above"})
    registration = reg_details.find("div", attrs={"class":"field-item even"}).get_text()
    reg_start = registration[:11]
    reg_end = registration[13:]

    for detail in event.find_all("ul"):
        details =detail.find("li")
        print(details)
```

```
<li class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" id="menu-1302-1"><a class="sf-depth-2" href="/hr/about" title="">About HR Services</a></li>
<li class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" id="menu-3617-1"><a class="sf-depth-2" href="/publications/news" title="">Latest News</a></li>
<li class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-2 sf-no-children" id="menu-791-1"><a class="sf-depth-2" href="/about-us/fccs-at-a-glance" title="">French Chamber at a Glance</a></li>
<li><a href="/node/6192/field_event_date/default/addtocal.ics">iCalendar</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jontan1/%20" target="_blank" title="Jonathan">Jonathan Tan</a>, Managing Director, Singapore at UnaBiz </li>
<li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/wandrille-doucerain-7bb1585/" target="_blank" title="Wandrille">Wandrille Doucerain</a>, CMO UnaBiz &amp; Head of IoT Asia at ENGIE</li>
```

Comment: DOM manipulating is huge concept. Beautiful Soup very easy to use for your Python works. So what did you try with bs4? Can you show your python code?

Comment: Yup I just updated it with my code. I was recommended to learn scrappy, but it just looks like outside of my league currently.